# ASP.NET MVC CheckBoxes Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Repository

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class GroupRepository
    {
        EgovtDataContext db = new EgovtDataContext();

```
    public IQueryable<Group> FindAllGroups()
    {
     return db.Groups;
    }

    public IQueryable<Group> FindGroups()
    {
        return from Group in FindAllGroups()
               orderby Group
               select Group;
    }



    public Group GetGroups(int id)
    {
        return db.Groups.SingleOrDefault(d => d.int_GroupId == id);
    }

    //


    public void Add(Group group)
    {
        db.Groups.InsertOnSubmit(group);
    }

    public void Delete(Group group)
    {

        db.Groups.DeleteOnSubmit(group);
    }

    //
    // Persistence 

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SubmitChanges();
    } 

}
```

}

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        GroupRepository grouprepository = new GroupRepository();

        ViewData["Group"] = grouprepository.FindGroups();

        return View();

    }

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>


<% foreach (Group i in ViewData["Group"] as List<Group>)

{ %>

   <input type="checkbox" name="Inhoud" 
          value="<%= i.int_GroupId %>" checked="checked" />

<% } %>
```

The thing is that it is not able to find group id and displaying the following error.  What is the solution?

```
CS1061: 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' does not contain a definition
 for 'int_GroupId' and no extension method 'int_GroupId' accepting a first 
 argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' could be found 
 (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: what does FindGroups() return? Is there some html missing?

Comment: public IQueryable<Group> FindGroups()
        {
            return from Group in FindAllGroups()
                   orderby Group
                   select Group;
        }

Comment: what is the namespace of Group? I'm guessing its not `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the namespace of the type your FindGroups() uses like so:

```
<% foreach (var i in ViewData["Group"] as List<MyNamespace.Blah.Group>)
   { %>
       <input type="checkbox" name="Inhoud" 
              value="<%= i.int_GroupId %>" checked="checked" />
<% } %>
```

or add a namespace reference to your Web.Config or add the namespace to your page header. I think you will still have a namespace conflict with `System.Text.RegularExpressions'.

MVC Style Look with LINQ

```
(ViewData["Group"] as List<MyNamespace.Blah.Group>)
    .ForEach(g => Response.Write(
        Html.CheckBox("Inhoud", true, new { value = g.int_GroupId })));
```

Comment: Where is the `.ForEach` coming from? Is that an extension method you have tacked onto IEnumerable?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx.  Very nice.

Comment: thanks! I don't know if it's more readable but it sure looks pretty and renders a checkbox how MVC wants you to.

Comment: well it worked ,Why it work with var and doesn't work in group

Answer (score 2):

Include your namespace for your Group class to your web.config pages/namespaces

```
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="Com.Example.Foo.Interfaces" />
        <add namespace="Com.Example.Foo.Common" />
        ...
    </namespaces>
  </pages
```

Use a view-specific model instead of generic ViewData and pass Groups as a property of the model so it can properly determine the type.

```
using Com.Example.Foo.Interfaces;
using Com.Example.Foo.Common;

public class GroupModel
{
     public IEnumerable<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GroupModel>" %> 

<% foreach (var i in Model.Groups) 
   { %> 
       <input type="checkbox" name="Inhoud"  
              value="<%= i.int_GroupId %>" checked="checked" /> 
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having a reference problem, the code in the aspx believes you are talking about `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group` rather than the type of Group you are returning from your `ActionResult`, where you use `Group` you will need to make sure it is the `Group` you want, either remove the using for the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, or if you need that, fully qualify `Group` with your namespace

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like this may be a `namespace issue`. 
`Group` is in the scope of `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group`, and I am guessing you have a table in your repos that is named Group. Try putting the namespace in for the type declaration in your forloop, that is of your repos so it doesnt confuse it with the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group` `namespace`.